# How to get horizontal black line when coloring cells?

Tags: tables, formatting, color, shading, colortbl

I have the following table with an arrow showing the missing black horizontal black line:

[image]

Here is the relevant code, I am wondering how do I get a black horizontal line where there is one missing?

```
\MyNumtwo{15.24}\\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{14}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}c|}{\textbf{$A\times{}B\pm{}C$} Program} \\ 
\hline
\textbf{Number of Incidents} & 
512 &
```

NOTE: I just realized that if you zoom in, the line is actually there.  But this is still potentially be a problem if someone is reading the PDF and doesn't see the line on their computer.  The line appears on the printout, but it appears to be ~1 pixel thinner than other horizontal lines.

If anyone knows a fix, please let me know.

Update: Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\graphicspath{/./}                  
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{F}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.65cm}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.76cm}}

\begin{table*}[t]
\small
\caption{Bunch of stuff in a table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|F|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|}
\hline
%\multirow{4}{*}
%{A} & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Stuff} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{13}{c|}{\textbf{More junk}} \\ 
\cline{2-14}
\vspace{-10pt}\textbf{Junk and stuff} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\textbf{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Garbage}} & 
\hline

%\textbf{Stuff here} & x & & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x\\ 
%\textbf{More stuff here} & 0 & 5.5 & 5.5 & 5.16 & 5.5 & 1.5 & 5.5 & 5.36 & 5.5 & 5.5 & 5.84 & 1.5 & 5.5\\  
\textbf{Stuff Here} & - & \textit{.5} & \textit{.5} & \textit{.5} & \textit{.5} & \textit{.5} & \textit{.5} & \textit{.5} & \textit{.5} & \textit{.5} & \textit{.5} & \textit{.1} & \textit{.1}\\  
\hline
\textbf{things} & 
\textit{.5} &
\textit{.5} &
\textit{.5} &
\textit{.5} &
\textit{.2} &
\textit{.2} &
\textit{.3} &
\textit{.4} &
\textit{.5} &
\textit{.5} &
\textit{.5} &
\textit{.5} &
\textit{.5} \\
\hline
\textbf{stuff} & 
- &
\textit{0} &
\textit{0} &
\textit{0} &
\textit{0} &
\textit{0} &
\textit{0} &
\textit{0} &
\textit{5} &
\textit{9} &
\textit{1} &
\textit{1} &
\textit{11} \\
\hline
\textbf{things} &
1 &
1 &
1 &
1 &
1 &
1 &
1 &
1 &
1 &
1 &
1 &
1 &
1 &
1 \\
\hline
\textbf{Number} & 
- &
\textit{1.111} &
\textit{111.111} &
\textit{111.111} &
\textit{111.111} &
\textit{111.111} &
\textit{111.111} &
\textit{111.111} &
\textit{111.111} &
\textit{111.111} &
\textit{9111.111} &
\textit{1111} &
\textit{111.1}\\ 

\hline
\multicolumn{14}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}c|}{\textbf{$A\times{}B\pm{}C$} Program} \\ 
\hline
\textbf{111 of 111} & 
111 &
111 &
111 &
111 &
111 &
111 &
111 &
111 &
111 &
111 &
111 &
111 &
111\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed minimal working example (MWE) that can be cut and pasted into an empty document so people can look at the problem and try things out? http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?rq=1 has some suggestions that you might find helpful.

Comment: I pasted my code with everything redacted. Hopefully I didn't introduce any bugs.

Comment: Don't forget that we need the preamble as well. Document classes and the packages you use are important. Cut the example down to the simplest possible document that gives the problem that you want to fix.

Comment: Are you sure this is not just some effect from your viewer? Try zooming in (using different zoom ratios) the page with the table to see if the rule really is there (you could also print the page with the table to make sure).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I already addressed what you said, read the question completely please.

Comment: I added the packages the document uses.

Comment: @sphere ah, sorry.

Comment: Does this appear in different PDF viewers, or just one (e.g. Acrobat)? COuld you provide some details of viewers you've tested this with?

Comment: Appears in Acrobat, most used PDF viewer in the world probably, therefore it needs to work in Acrobat because that is the viewer the people reading this document will almost definitely use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please always post complete documents, not just fragments, if you had added `\documentclass{article}` to your code and tested it you would have seen that it generated errors:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

(twice)

Once that is fixed, the remaining problem is really a failure in acrobat, xpdf does better as may be seen on the left here:

[image]

You can however make it easier for acrobat by drawing the rule on top of the grey panel:

```
\textit{111.1}\\ 
\multicolumn{14}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}c|}{\textbf{$A\times{}B\pm{}C$} Program} \\
\noalign{\vskip-12pt}
\hline 
\noalign{\vskip12pt}
\hline
\textbf{111 of 111} &
```

acrobat then does better:

[image]

Comment: I wonder how you aquire the 12pt? How can I get the value when I have a paragraphed row (columntype p{10cm})?

Comment: @PeterMiehle it's `\normalbaselineskip` I would guess (5 years later:-)

Comment: sorry asking questions in comments on a 5 year old answer doesn't work:-) Make an example and ask a new question I can't guess what you mean otherwise

Comment: thanks. I just came over this answer after I ask already. I delete my second question.