# How to set tikzmarks with \noalign at the edge of tabular rows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tex-core, tikzmark

I'm trying to improve the lines in a tabular with colored rows (lines above a colored row can disappear in the adobe reader at some zoom levels) by redrawing the line above a row after the row itself has be created. I have p-columns so I can't use David's solution here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129835/2388.

So I thought to use tikzmark (or some other mark) but can't figure[1] out how to find the right edge. Whatever I do the right mark is at the right side of the page:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arrayrulewidth{4pt}

\begin{tabular}{l}
abc    \\\noalign{\hrule height \arrayrulewidth}
blub   \\\noalign{\pgfmark{testa}\hfill\pgfmark{testb}}
abc\tikz [remember picture] \draw [overlay,->] (pic cs:testa)--(pic cs:testb);
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Is there anyway to put the marks in the \noalign so that they respect the size of the tabular box like `\hrule` does it?

[1] I naturally can find the edge by putting a mark at the right end of some cell and then calculate the intersection but this is cheating ;-).

Comment: Well, I just *have* to vote up this question, don't I?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As egreg said, but as you hinted you were using `colortbl` it is already putting a coloured rule under the cell, so you can just ask it to stick a tikzmark at each end of that, so you know where it is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\makeatletter
\newcount\U@CT@
\def\CT@@do@color{%
\U@tm
  \global\let\CT@do@color\relax
        \@tempdima\wd\z@
        \advance\@tempdima\@tempdimb
        \advance\@tempdima\@tempdimc
        \kern-\@tempdimb
        \leaders\vrule
%^^A                     \@height\p@\@depth\p@
                \hskip\@tempdima\@plus  1fill
\U@tm
        \kern-\@tempdimc
        \hskip-\wd\z@ \@plus -1fill }


\def\U@tm{%
\global\advance\U@CT@\@ne
\tikzmark{test\the\U@CT@}}
%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arrayrulewidth{4pt}

\begin{tabular}{l}
\rowcolor{yellow}abc    \\
blub   \\
abc\tikz [remember picture] \draw [overlay,->] (pic cs:test1)--(pic cs:test2);
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you want the left edge of the arrow to be the left edge of the colour rather than the cell contents, move the first `\U@tm` down a few lines after the `\kern-\@tempdimb`

Comment: That's a quite interesting idea. I could even put the code for line directly in the `\U@tm`. Is there a way to know the height of the cell at this moment so that I can shift the line to the top?

Comment: Not directly (that's why `colortbl` uses a `\leaders\vline\hskip..` as it doesn't know the vertical extent. However you could of course also do you as you did originally and put  another tikzmark in a `\noalign` before the row and use its vertical position.

Comment: yes. While sitting in the concert I realized that this the same situation as in the horizontal case: only hrule and vrule "know" the space.

Comment: Getting the vertical position of a hline in longtable isn't easy: The simple `\hline\noalign{\tikzmark{hline}}` doesn't work at page breaks: The hline is not repeated on the second page and the tikzmark is on the wrong page. And when redefining `\LT@@hline` one must be careful as colortbl redefines it too at the begin of the document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry:-) In a future life I'll write longtable knowing about colortbl, and with the necessary hooks so colortbl doesn't need to redefine it:-)

Answer (score 11):

The contents of `\noalign` is appended to the enclosing vertical list at the specified point; the enclosing vertical list is a `\vbox`, `\vtop` or `\vcenter` depending on the optional argument to `tabular` (default `\vcenter`).

Your `\hfill` starts a paragraph, which will use the current `\hsize`, so you get an unwanted vertical space and the arrow will be as wide as `\linewidth`.

The enclosing box's width is not known until the `\halign` is unpacked as a list of horizontal boxes. For measuring it one can hook in `\endtabular`, after the `\crcr\egroup` that finishes off the `\halign`, using `\lastbox` tricks.

For instance,

```
\def\endtabular{\crcr\egroup\tabularhook\egroup$\egroup}
\newdimen\tabularwidth
\def\tabularhook{%
  \setbox0=\lastbox
  \global\tabularwidth=\wd0
  \nointerlineskip\box0 }
```

will store in `\tabularwidth` the width of the just ended `tabular`. But it's too late for your purposes.

Inserting a “phantom line” does the job:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\measureit}[3]{%
  \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]
  \multicolumn{#1}{@{}c@{}}{%
    \pgfmark{#2}\hfill\pgfmark{#3}}%
  \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arrayrulewidth{4pt}

\begin{tabular}{l}
abc    \\\noalign{\hrule height \arrayrulewidth}
blub   \measureit{1}{testa}{testb}
abc\tikz [remember picture] \draw [overlay,->] (pic cs:testa)--(pic cs:testb);
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}{l}
abc    \\\noalign{\hrule height \arrayrulewidth}
blub   \\
abc
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not a nice syntax and probably improvable.

Comment: I want to use the code in longtable too, so patching \endtabular is not really an option. The multicolumn-approach is neat, but one needs to know the number of cell.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer With `longtable` you can access at the table width, at least the "tentative" one, which stabilizes to the final one after some runs; I'm sure David will be able to concoct something for this. The `\endtabular` trick might be used for storing the width in the `.aux` file and reuse the information at the next run for building a zero height box to feed into `\noalign` with the pgfmarks inside it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  For longtable you could just look in `\LT@i` or whatever the table number is. looking after the tabular with `\lastbox` is exactly what longtable is doing anyway.

Comment: @davidcarlisle : I know how how to get the width of a longtable. There is some code here somewhere (from Heiko i think) . But at first I'm trying to find code which works with tabular too.

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of the package `nicematrix` creates PGF/Tikz nodes corresponding to the position of the potential horizontal and vertical rules.

In the following example, we use those nodes to draw (with Tikz) a rectangle with a thick red line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
\hline
   one & two & three & four \\
\hline
   five & six & seven & eight \\
\hline
   nine & ten & eleven & twelve \\
\hline
\CodeAfter
   \tikz \draw [thick, red] (2-|2) rectangle (3-|4) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]