# row color and a toggle

Tags: etoolbox, colortbl, rowcolor

I'd like to create a new command that I would repeat in front of each row, and which would colorize the row if a toggle is true, and would leave it uncolored if the toggle is false. I would change the state of the toggle at some specific places, for the following rows to be colorized or not.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\newtoggle{fond}
\providecommand{\chfd}%
    {\iftoggle{fond}%
        {\rowcolor[rgb]{.95,.95,1}}%
        {}%
    }%

\toggletrue{fond}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
1 & 2 \\

\hline

\chfd a & b \\
\togglefalse{fond}%
\chfd c & d \\
\chfd e & f \\
%\toggletrue{fond}
\chfd g & h \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: And here is what I get]

Appart from the \hline (which seems to be cancelled by the following \chfd), it does what I expect up to the 'd' cell. But why is the e-f row colorized back? I would expect the toggle to have stayed in its 'false' state, and the row to be uncolored?

And I would expect to have to set the toggle to 'true' for the g-h row to be colorized... Actually it is colorized anyway, and if I uncomment the %\toggletrue{fond} I get an error :

```
Misplaced \noalign.
\rowcolor ->\noalign 
                     {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \global \let \CT@do@color \CT@@do@color...
l.30 \chfd
           g & h \\
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at `\rowcolors` in the [xcolor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package. It does what (I think) you want. See page 35 of the `xcolor` documentation for a good example.

Comment: in tabular each column is group so `\togglefalse{fond}` is local to that raw (in fact to first column)
you need to make it global by `\global\togglefalse{fond}`

Comment: @touhami: I think it's rather an issue of an incomplete test

Comment: @ChristianHupfer well, yes, there is 2 issues

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What do you mean by _an incomplete test_?

Comment: @Olivier: Well, my comment goes into the same direction as Ulrike's answer: The test of `\iftoggle` isn't completed due to the group feature of a `tabular` cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\rowcolors` is (like `\multicolumn`) rather picky. It wants to be the first thing in a row. So you can't execute every code before it. With `\togglefalse` it doesn't matter as the `\rowcolors` is then not seen, but `\toogletrue` should be either in the cell before or hidden in a `\noalign`. In both cases it then must be global:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\newtoggle{fond}
\providecommand{\chfd}%
    {\iftoggle{fond}%
        {\rowcolor[rgb]{.95,.95,1}}%
        {}%
    }%

\togglefalse{fond}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\chfd a & b \global\toggletrue{fond} \\
\chfd c & d \\
\end{tabular}

\togglefalse{fond}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\chfd a & b \\\noalign{\global\toggletrue{fond}}
\chfd c & d \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ulrike, it works. I'm still not quite sure that my code is really correct, because as I mentioned the \hline seems to be cancelled by the following \chfd. But that's not as important and I can live with it.

Comment: The \hline is there, but rowcolors can (partly) overwrite them. I normally redraw the lines later e.g. with tikz, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134263/how-to-set-tikzmarks-with-noalign-at-the-edge-of-tabular-rows

Comment: A solution is often to use `\hhline` instead of `\hline`.